# (Haskell) Displaying a list in plain English?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I've been writing a really simple text game engine, and I've come across a problem: I need to be able to print a list of items in plain english. So essentially, I need a function that takes an array of strings and outputs them like how an English speaker would say them. For example:

```
showEnglish ["door", "car", "cat", "apple"] = "a door, a car, a cat, and an apple."
```

Is there a clean and fast way to do this in haskell? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem 1: In English, some words get prefixed with "a", while others get "an". It ought to be possible to fix that like so:

```
prefixWord :: String -> String
prefixWord "" = ""
prefixWord word =
  if (toLower $ head $ word) `elem` "aeiou"
    then "an " ++ word
    else "a "  ++ word
```

Problem 2: Join them all together, with an "and" at the end.

```
joinWords :: [String] -> String
joinWords ws = (intercalate ", " (init ws)) ++ " and " ++ last ws
```

Put it all together:

```
showEnglish :: [String] -> String
showEnglish = joinWords . map prefixWord
```

Comment: @CarstenKönig Building grammatically correct sentences is something that even MS Word has a hard time doing, and that program was built by a huge team of developers over the last 20 or so years with lots of experts in the field.  I think this answer should suffice for stackoverflow ;)

Comment: It illustrates the basic approach. For "a text game", this plus a few fudge factors is probably enough. For a linguistic analysis program, probably not so much...

Comment: Should `last w` be `last ws` instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the [indefinite determiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner) for a word, roughly speaking, using [indefiniteDet](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/minimorph-0.1.5.0/docs/NLP-Minimorph-English.html#v:indefiniteDet) from the [minimorph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/minimorph) package. It looks like the package is intended for just this "ad hoc" usage. It also has a function to insert commas, which unfortunately is anathema because it omits the [Oxford comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma). So maybe just use `intercalate` instead. But:

```
showEnglish :: [Text] -> Text
showEnglish = commas "and" . map (\w -> indefiniteDet w `append` " " `append` w)

ghci> showEnglish ["door", "car", "cat", "apple"]
"a door, a car, a cat and an apple"
```

And now we don't need to hard-code simplified expectations of English morphology... we'll leave that to whoever wrote `minimorph`.